# How to Integrate my python code to my tkinter interface?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have made a program where the user enter's a target number and 4 other numbers to make that target number. Right now I am having trouble to intergrate my tkinter interface to my code. So I am hoping that some one can help me

## Tkinter interface:

```
window = Tk()
window.title("target number solution")
Label(window,image='', bg="white") .grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
Label(window, text="Enter target number:",bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N)
textentry = Entry(window, width=20, bg="white")
textentry.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=N)


Label(window, text="Enter first number:",bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold").grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=N)
textentry = Entry(window, width=20, bg="white")
textentry.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=N)


Label(window, text="Enter second number:",bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold").grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=N)
textentry = Entry(window, width=20, bg="white")
textentry.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=N)


Label(window, text="Enter third number:",bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold").grid(row=8, column=0, sticky=N)
textentry = Entry(window, width=20, bg="white")
textentry.grid(row=9, column=0, sticky=N)


Label(window, text="Enter fourth number:",bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold").grid(row=10, column=0, sticky=N)
textentry = Entry(window, width=20, bg="white")
textentry.grid(row=11, column=0, sticky=N)


Button(window, text="Solve", width=6, command=solver).grid(row=12, column=0, sticky=N)
output = Text(window, width=60, height=10, wrap=WORD, background="white")
output.grid(row=13, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky=N)


window.mainloop()
```

[image: This is what the interface looks like]

This is the code that needs to be linked with the tkinter interface:

```
from itertools import permutations,combinations_with_replacement
numbers   = []
target    = int(input())
operators = ["+","-","*","/"]
groups    = ['X+X+X+X', 'X+X+(X+X)', 'X+(X+X)+X', '(X+X+X)+X', '(X+X)+X+X', 'X+(X+X+X)', '((X+X)+X)+X', 'X+(X+(X+X))', 'X+((X+X)+X)', '(X+X)+(X+X)', '(X+(X+X))+X']
seen      = set()
for values in permutations(numbers,len(numbers)):
    for operCombo in combinations_with_replacement(operators,len(numbers)-1):
        for oper in permutations(operCombo,len(numbers)-1):
            formulaKey = "".join(oper+values)
            if formulaKey in seen: continue # ignore variations on parentheses alone
            for pattern in groups:
                formula = "".join(o+p for o,p in zip([""]+list(oper), pattern.split("+")))
                formula = "".join(v+p for v,p in zip([""]+list(values),formula.split("X")))
                try:
                    if eval(formula) == target:
                        global Answer
                        Answer = formula,"=",target
                        print(formula,"=",target)
                        seen.add(formulaKey)
                        break
                except: pass
```

All suggestions will be grealty appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the values for each number in seperate `IntVar` variables, then get the values of these variables inside the `solver` function and perform all the operations that are in your second code. The code should be modularised with the use of a class containing functions that create the widgets and run the `solver` code. To read more about class-based declarations in Tkinter, read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#a-simple-hello-world-program).

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label, Button, IntVar, Entry, Text, W, N, WORD, INSERT
from itertools import permutations,combinations_with_replacement



class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets() 


    def create_widgets(self):

        self.target_num = IntVar()
        self.num1 = IntVar()
        self.num2 = IntVar()
        self.num3 = IntVar()
        self.num4 = IntVar()       
        # self.title("target number solution")

        Label(self,image='', bg="white").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        Label(self, text="Enter target number:", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N)
        self.textentry1 = Entry(self, textvariable=self.target_num, width=20, bg="white")
        self.textentry1.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=N)


        Label(self, text="Enter first number:",bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold").grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=N)
        self.textentry2 = Entry(self, textvariable=self.num1, width=20, bg="white")
        self.textentry2.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=N)


        Label(self, text="Enter second number:",bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold").grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=N)
        self.textentry3 = Entry(self, textvariable=self.num2, width=20, bg="white")
        self.textentry3.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=N)


        Label(self, text="Enter third number:",bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold").grid(row=8, column=0, sticky=N)
        self.textentry3 = Entry(self, textvariable=self.num3, width=20, bg="white")
        self.textentry3.grid(row=9, column=0, sticky=N)


        Label(self, text="Enter fourth number:",bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold").grid(row=10, column=0, sticky=N)
        self.textentry4 = Entry(self, textvariable=self.num4, width=20, bg="white")
        self.textentry4.grid(row=11, column=0, sticky=N)


        Button(self, text="Solve", width=6, command=self.solver).grid(row=12, column=0, sticky=N)
        self.output = Text(self, width=60, height=10, wrap=WORD, background="white")
        self.output.grid(row=13, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky=N)

    def solver(self):
        target = self.target_num.get()
        number1 = self.num1.get()
        number2 = self.num2.get()
        number3 = self.num3.get()
        number4 = self.num4.get()
        numbers = [number1, number2, number3, number4]
        operators = ["+","-","*","/"]
        groups    = ['X+X+X+X', 'X+X+(X+X)', 'X+(X+X)+X', '(X+X+X)+X', '(X+X)+X+X', 'X+(X+X+X)', '((X+X)+X)+X', 'X+(X+(X+X))', 'X+((X+X)+X)', '(X+X)+(X+X)', '(X+(X+X))+X']
        seen = set()
        for values in permutations(numbers,len(numbers)):
            for operCombo in combinations_with_replacement(operators,len(numbers)-1):
                for oper in permutations(operCombo,len(numbers)-1):
                    formulaKey = "".join(str(oper+values))
                    if formulaKey in seen: continue # ignore variations on parentheses alone
                    for pattern in groups:
                        formula = "".join(str(o)+str(p) for o,p in zip([""]+list(oper), pattern.split("+")))
                        formula = "".join(str(v)+str(p) for v,p in zip([""]+list(values),formula.split("X")))
                        try:
                            if eval(formula) == target:                              
                                Answer = formula,"=",target
                                print(formula,"=",target)
                                seen.add(formulaKey)
                                #insert value in output Textbox
                                self.output.insert(INSERT, Answer) 
                                self.output.insert(END, '\n') 
                                break
                        except: pass

root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.master.title("target number solution")
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bob\Desktop\24 solutions test.py", line 6, in <module>
    target_num = IntVar()
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 502, in __init__
    Variable.__init__(self, master, value, name)
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 317, in __init__
    self._root = master._root()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'`

Comment: The code has been edited and fully tested. You can try it out.

Comment: it works but in the output box it gets shown in this format:`(1+1+1)*8 = 248*(1+1+1) = 24` I want it that each solution is shown on separate lines

Comment: ok, i've edited to include newline('\n') for every `Answer` added to the output box.

Comment: nope it still doesn't work it still gets showm in the format that I mentioned

Comment: wait I fixed it its suppose to be this `self.output.insert(INSERT, '\n')`

Comment: I have another problem, When I first enter the numbers the solutions show up but when I enter a different set of numbers the old solutions stay in the box they do not get cleared so could you help me

Comment: You can use `self.output.delete(1.0, END)`. Reference: [Official Docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#patterns)

Comment: I have put it there but now when I enter the numbers and click solve nothing comes up

Comment: I think it should be added at the beginning of the `solver` function. This will make sure the TextBox is cleared before anything is added from the for loops.

Comment: it works now but I changed `END` to `INSERT` because for some reason when I use `END` I get an error

Answer (score 0):

A few things that you can change/try:

- Keep the "Entry" variables unique. Then extract each number using .get() command.
- Use lambda in the command options of the Button as follows:

  command = lambda: solver(num1, num2, num3, num4)
- And if you want to display your returned number from 'solver', grid a Label in your tkinter window. Then use `Label.config(text="Your number here")` to show it in your tkinter window